# Swift - How to refresh NavigationController Menu Bar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, refresh, viewwillappear

Is there a method called, similar to viewwillappear that will refresh the navigationcontroller menu bar at the top of a view?

Answer (score 0):

`navigationController?.navigationBar` doesn't need to be reloaded. You just have to change it's properties (tint color, background color, title, etc...). You can change all of this from currently presented viewController.